Kubernetes Upgrade from version 1.27.x to 1.30.x
I'd like to upgrade our Kubernetes Clusters from version 1.27.x to 1.30.x using kubeadm.
Is is possible to do the upgrade in one step or do I really need to upgrade from 1.27 to 1.28, 1.28 to 1.29 and 1.29 to 1.30?
When I try to upgrade to v1.30.3 directly, I get the following error -
# kubeadm upgrade apply v1.30.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
[upgrade] Running cluster health checks
[upgrade/version] You have chosen to change the cluster version to "v1.30.3"
[upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.27.1
[upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.30.3
[upgrade/version] FATAL: the --version argument is invalid due to these fatal errors:

    - Specified version to upgrade to "v1.30.3" is too high; kubeadm can upgrade only 1 minor version at a time

Please fix the misalignments highlighted above and try upgrading again
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

What is the best way going forward? I'd like to avoid doing multiple upgrade causing multiple production cluster outages. Thanks!

As the error says, - Specified version to upgrade to "v1.30.3" is too high; kubeadm can upgrade only 1 minor version at a time, skipping minor versions is not supported.
See also: kubeadm-upgrade

Skipping MINOR versions when upgrading is unsupported. For more details, please visit Version Skew Policy.

You must upgrade to each minor version separately, in this case, a minimum of 3 upgrades.
The only alternative to avoid this is to simply create a new cluster in 1.30.3, and move your workloads to the new cluster, abandoning the old cluster instead.

unfortunately the answer I expected :( not very user-friendly and a tiring task given the number of clusters we have. thanks anyway!

The point of controlling the upgrades is because there's a compatibility guarantee between the control plane and the worker nodes so you can always run the two on +/- one different minor version. If you upgrade the control plane all the way to 1.30.x leaving your nodes on 1.27.x there's no guarantee that would work, however upgrading the control plane to 1.28.x is guaranteed to work with the nodes still on 1.27.x.
